# Nested imports in python

Tags: python, import, python-import

I know this is a newbie question but I can't seem to get this to work.

I have the following folder structure:

```
├──package
|    ├── __init__.py
|    └── subpackage
|         ├── __init__.py
|         ├── module0.py
|         └── module1.py
└── test.py
```

- `module0.py` has `function0` that I would like to call in `test.py`.
- `module0.py` imports `module1.py` like this: `import module1`.
- `function0` is imported in `test.py` like this: `from package.subpackage.module0 import function0`.

whenever I import the function in `test.py` I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'`. How do you suggest I should do the imports?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
├──package
|    ├── __init__.py
|    └── subpackage
|         ├── __init__.py
|         ├── module0.py
|         └── module1.py
└── test.py       
└── __init__.py
```

I think you also need init file at the top level.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your quick reply. But this didn't work.

Comment: what is the name of your project? The name of the higher-level directory for package.